# RSA Decrypted Data Corrupt

Tags: php, character-encoding, encryption

My script uses `openssl_private_decrypt()` to decrypt a string encrypted with RSA in another program.  Currently it writes to a file.  But when I try to open it up in a text editor, it says it can't detect the encoding.  If I try to echo it, nothing appears.  If I output it's length, I get `256`, instead of the correct `3`.

I know the decryption is done right because using the `cat` terminal command on the output file gives the correct data.

```
$ cat decrypted.txt
```

It looks like this is a character encoding problem, a problem I hear can give a lot of pain in PHP.  I even tried `utf8_encode()`.  What might the problem be?

Here's the code:

```
$results = '';
openssl_private_decrypt(
    base64_decode(
        <<<EOS
QWlG+AZIt9GE0hw0wwcPRtUWueMLBxj3YWpa5zQBoz1ttnt7TvlxDtYWZcvaUL/qr2CJCADE2iTR
G72FhAwew2fhqlqmsxL7Nns3yegflTTMXyilVM3mPU4Cx94ylLfa+ZrqrNEepaRorNJ/js5iTq9i
avegO/kYOv4zhEsZirlk/Mj0vVv6irWo8WyZoCDC2SwfGWeSUI8F4pq4FUkRh9V/0zAUZ+3P0A7Z
SrA80dSa6U/J+poRcmE1vRLQXvM8dBtFRKmb0zfltLUBMcMhcglzAhcpemJ99OCZmUuynFRcRNkj
CkOLsO+lSHntcbmXqsKE+of78gnU3tp5hHSHIg==
EOS
    ),
    $results,
    openssl_pkey_get_private(
        // load private key
    ),
    OPENSSL_NO_PADDING
);
echo $results;
```

Comment: please provide us with your code and sample input

Comment: In particular, can you show us the code you use to write the encrypted string to the file, and then the code you use to read it back out?  Also, you totally should not use `utf8_encode/decode` here.  Encrypted data is a stream of bytes, not a stream of characters.

Comment: The length difference could also be due to the encrypt function padding your original data out to the crypt algorithm's required block size.

Comment: @Charles: actually I'm receiving it via a HTTP POST request.  Just `$_POST['data']`.

Comment: Sorry but the code you provided is not reproductable.

Comment: @Jonah, are you sure that the other side encrypted the data using `NO_PADDING`?  Getting the padding wrong will yield incorrect results.

Comment: @AbiusX: the problem is that I didn't put in the private key.  But I'm sure that the decryption is going fine, because I can see the data just fine with `cat`.

Comment: @Charles: yes, no padding.  No nothing, just basic RSA for now.

Comment: The fact that you're getting a decrypted length of a single block instead of the length of your expected data is really, really pointing towards a padding thing.  Can you show us the code you use to perform the original encryption?

Comment: @Charles: Aha!  They were both set to no padding.  But I changed both the other program and this one to the default (PKCS1), and it works fine now.  Put that down as an answer if you like :) Thanks!

Comment: Answered!  Though I do find it funny that it would malfunction when expressly told to not use padding on either side.  Ah well.

Comment: @Charles: I don't understand it either.  The Java end was set to use `NoPadding`, and PHP was set to use `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING`.  Thanks again, you rock!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're getting decrypted data exactly the length of a single block instead of the length of your expected data is really, really pointing towards a [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) problem.

Make sure you're using the same [padding flag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.padding.php) on both sides.

Comment: Thanks, I set both sides to use PKCS1 instead of none, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with openssl_private_decrypt, but it seems logical to me that you would provide base64_encode()'d data to openssl_private_encrypt().

In such case, you're mangling your data by running in the wrong order on decrypt.

Seems like you would want to decrypt the string first, then run base64_decode() on the unencrypted string.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately not the case.  In my other program (actually written in Java), I encrypt the data, and then base64 encode it to safely send it over HTTP to this script.